# await defer constructor, async constructor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

Is it possible in `iced coffee script` to make async constructor:

```
class Animal
  constructor: (autocb) ->
    #some async action here
```

And call it like:

```
await new Animal, defer(animal)
```

When I try to do it, got error:

```
unexpected ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CoffeeScript commas are used as separators for arguments. For example:

```
add 2, 3
```

Optionally you may put parentheses around arguments to make it more explicit:

```
add(2, 3)
```

However you may not put a comma between the function and the arguments:

```
add, 2, 3   # not allowed
add(, 2, 3) # can you see your mistake?
```

The same goes for constructor functions:

```
new Animal defer(animal)  # this is ok
new Animal(defer(animal)) # defer(animal) is just an argument
```

However you can't put a comma between `new Animal` and the first argument:

```
new Animal, defer(animal)   # not allowed
new Animal(, defer(animal)) # can you see your mistake?
```

The same goes for `await`:

```
await new Animal defer(animal)  # this is ok
await new Animal(defer(animal)) # again defer(animal) is just an argument
```

However you can't put a comma between the function and the first argument:

```
await new Animal, defer(animal)   # not allowed
await new Animal(, defer(animal)) # can you see your mistake?
```

So to answer your question: yes, it is possible to make an async constructor in iced coffee script. Like all asynchronous functions the last argument must always be the callback function generated by `defer`.

Next time when the compiler says `unexpected ,` just remove the comma. It's as simple as that.